# Assign group numbers within IDs to rows separated by zeros

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
ID<-rep(c("A","B"),times=c(4,8))
Group<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
data<-data.frame(ID,Group)
data

 ID Group
 A     1
 A     1
 A     0
 A     1
 B     1
 B     1
 B     0
 B     1
 B     1
 B     1
 B     0
 B     1
```

I want to create a column called “Number”, where consecutive rows where Group=1 are all assigned the same number. This number should start at 1 and go up with the next group of consecutive rows. When Group = 0, I want the corresponding Number value to be equal to 0.
I also want the Numbers row to reset to 1 once the ID changes.

Here is an example of what this would look like:

```
ID Group Number
A     1      1
A     1      1
A     0      0
A     1      2
B     1      1
B     1      1
B     0      0
B     1      2
B     1      2
B     1      2
B     0      0
B     1      3
```

I'm thinking of using the functions group_by and mutate in Dplyr, but I'm unsure what to do beyond that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a `cumsum` trick, applied with `ave`, to get the `Number`'s on each group of `ID`.

```
data$Number <- ave(data$Group, data$ID, FUN = function(G){
  G*(cumsum(G == 0) + (G[1] == 1))
})

data
#   ID Group Number
#1   A     1      1
#2   A     1      1
#3   A     0      0
#4   A     1      2
#5   B     1      1
#6   B     1      1
#7   B     0      0
#8   B     1      2
#9   B     1      2
#10  B     1      2
#11  B     0      0
#12  B     1      3
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, grp := rleid(Group), ID][, Number := 0]
data[Group == 1, Number := match(grp, unique(grp)), Group][, grp := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rle` in base R :

```
transform(data, Number = ave(Group, ID, FUN = function(x) 
  with(rle(x == 1), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))))

#   ID Group Number
#1   A     1      1
#2   A     1      1
#3   A     0      0
#4   A     1      2
#5   B     1      1
#6   B     1      1
#7   B     0      0
#8   B     1      2
#9   B     1      2
#10  B     1      2
#11  B     0      0
#12  B     1      3
```